# Chrome Address Bar Javascript produces different effect than Console

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, address-bar

Trying something new, I was attempting to highlight text on [this wikia page](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Story_and_History#Ballas.27_Rebellion_and_Allying_With_Hunhow) using javascript within the address bar (i.e. using "javascript:[code]").

When running the following code sample through Chrome's console, it produces the desired effect. When running it from the address bar, it results in only the affected text -- the rest of the page body is removed.

```
javascript:txt = document.getElementById("Ballas.27_Rebellion_and_Allying_With_Hunhow").parentElement.nextElementSibling;index = txt.innerHTML.indexOf(", but")+2;txt.innerHTML = txt.innerHTML.substring(0,index)+"<span style='background-color:yellow;'>"+txt.innerHTML.substring(index,index+40)+"</span>"+txt.innerHTML.substring(index+40);
```

*Note: if you want to try this you will have to manually type `javascript:` into the address bar before pasting the code, as Chrome automatically removes it.*

I'm curious as to why this would be, and also if there is a way to stop the address bar from removing the rest of the page body. Can anyone offer insight?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick solution to the problem you're experiencing is to add `false;` to the end of your query. This will prevent Chrome from removing the text from your page and should give you the result you expect.

Here's the fixed code:

```
javascript:txt = document.getElementById("Ballas.27_Rebellion_and_Allying_With_Hunhow").parentElement.nextElementSibling;index = txt.innerHTML.indexOf(", but")+2;txt.innerHTML = txt.innerHTML.substring(0,index)+"<span style='background-color:yellow;'>"+txt.innerHTML.substring(index,index+40)+"</span>"+txt.innerHTML.substring(index+40);false;
```

To fully answer the question, let me quickly explain what is happening. I'll start by splitting up your JS a bit to make it easier to read.

```
txt = document.getElementById("Ballas.27_Rebellion_and_Allying_With_Hunhow").parentElement.nextElementSibling;

index = txt.innerHTML.indexOf(", but")+2;

txt.innerHTML = txt.innerHTML.substring(0,index) +
  "<span style='background-color:yellow;'>" +
  txt.innerHTML.substring(index,index+40) +
  "</span>"+txt.innerHTML.substring(index+40);
```

What you'll note is that the final statement is an assignment operation. In JavaScript the result of an assignment operation is the value of the assignment. In other words, if we say `return x = 1` we will both set the value of `x` to `1` and return the value `1`.

This brings us to the reason why Chrome is replacing your page content. The JavaScript you're providing is returning the content of the `txt` element (the paragraph you're deciding to highlight) and this is then being treated as the content of your new page, the same way that visiting `data:text/plain,hello world` or `javascript:"hello world"` in your browser will show the text "hello world"even though you haven't explicitly visited a website.

To fix this, you can return a `falsey` value in JavaScript - this means any one of the following:

- `0`
- `false`
- `[]`
- `null`
- `undefined`

Hence, adding `false;` at the end of your JavaScript will have Chrome run the code but not show the resulting text and will prevent it from changing the page content on you unexpectedly.

Comment: That's pretty cool. Thanks for the knowledge!

However, when I use that Chrome throws a "SyntaxError: Illegal Return Statement" (in both console and address bar)

Comment: Simply ending with "false" instead of "return false" works! Thanks.

Comment: Good catch, I've updated the answer to reflect that.